# Why the sklearn doesn't excuse imputer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

When I try the above statement, got the following warning. why is it raising a warning for this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO; please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as the links above to see why images of code & exceptions are not useful.

Comment: This is not an error, just a warning which is self-explanatory on what it wants. The question is what you want to do? You want to remove that warning, hide that warning, or follow that warning?

Comment: Hello Vivek , thank you for your support .. I just want to understand what it wants so that I can solve it ...

Answer (score 0):

As you cab see in the warning that SimpleImputer class is moved to a different module in the version 0.22, Hence you are getting the depreciation warning now.

To get rid of the warning, you could use the following

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```